# MySQL SELECT WHERE only digits, spaces and one slash

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

How can I SELECT my_column FROM my_table, but my_column may only contain digits (0-9), spaces ( ) and ONE slash (/). More than one slashes are not allowed (per field). Other characters are not allowed.

Can any body give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: Pls post some sample input and desired output...

Comment: Do you want to select only rows with column that answer that criteria or do you want to select all rows but to remove the undesired characters from the column?

Comment: I want to select only rows with column that answer that criteria. I don't want to remove anything.

Comment: BTW: Question already answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regexp`:

```
SELECT my_column
FROM my_table
WHERE my_column REGEXP '^[0-9 ]*/[0-9 ]*$';
```